# iOS download non-consumable content from server with in-app purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I've read and searched all I could on the iOS in-app topic. At least from Google (minus the endless in-app hacking links). One thing that I am not able to find is instructions or tutorials on how to grab the content from the server and storing it onto the phone after receipt verification. I get that I can either store the content on my own server or package it up using application loader and have Apple host it. I get the whole non-consumable content and using your own server or NSUserDefaults to remember purchased items. What I can't find is coding tutorials on how to get the in-app purchase content from either my own server or Apple's and where on the phone can I store it? normal socket call? can I store the content in the app's directory?

As an example, I have an existing app that I would like to sell new images via in-app purchases. The existing images are in a bundle. How do I go about getting the bundled images from the server back into my app? I'm okay with new bundles for each purchase, I understand that you cannot modify an existing bundle.

Answer (score 3):

When ever your purchase is successful, you will get the transaction object. Isn't it?

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Iterate through each transaction object and use the following code:

```
if (transaction.downloads)
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
}
```

On successful download, you will get a delegate call:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
{
    for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
    {
        switch (download.downloadState) {
            case SKDownloadStateActive:
                NSLog(@"Download progress = %f and Download time: %f", download.progress, download.timeRemaining);
                break;
            case SKDownloadStateFinished:
                NSLog(@"%@",download.contentURL);
                // Download is complete. Content file URL is at
                // path referenced by download.contentURL. Move
                // it somewhere safe, unpack it and give the user
                // access to it
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

After downloading, you will get the URL where the data is downloaded, now you can store in the library's application support folder and prevent it from auto sync to cloud (if necessary). That's it.

Comment: I did exactly the same way. And the download url seems not to be there after I got the SKDownloadStateFinished event. (I'm using [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[download.contentURL absoluteString] to check or using something like iFunBox to check). Any idea?

Comment: @bagusflyer, did you check if your purchase is successful first? There might be some configuration issue on itunesconnect.

Comment: Thanks @Satyam svv, I suddenly can get the file if I use:


                    NSString* srcPath = [[download.contentURL relativePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"];
                   
                    if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:srcPath)

Comment: @Satyamsvv I had implemented the Hosting feature and able to donwload the content from iTunes using download.contentURL.How can I write/transfer this package to application document directory in the SKDownloadStateFinished state ? I am not able to unpack it so I can access it.

Comment: @AjaySharma In the method "- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads", downloads is an array of "SKDownload", the object of SKDownload will have "contentURL" from which you can find the location to which it downloaded. From there, you can copy. Also its just a zip. You can unzip it if you want.

Comment: @Satyamsvv I am already using the same delegate method, but facing issue while writing it into another directory.How should I copy it into usable directory.

Comment: @AjaySharma can you show me the code that you are writing to copy. Are you using NSFileManager? Did you check if the src file exists before copying?